# Problem with searching multiple keywords using google custom search API

Tags: python, google-custom-search

I am trying to search for multiple keywords (in the list of **filteredList**) and get a list of each search result. This is the code I have tried below:

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import csv
import pprint

my_api_key = "xxx"
my_cse_id = "xxx"


def google_search(search_term, api_key, cse_id, **kwargs):
    service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)
    res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id, **kwargs).execute()
    return res['items']


filteredList = ['Optimal Elektronika',
                'Evrascon',
                ]

words = [
    'vakansiya'
    ]

newDictList = []

# this is the htmlSnippets, link and also htmlTitle for filtering over the list of the dictionaries
keyValList = ['link', 'htmlTitle', 'htmlSnippet']

for word in filteredList:
    results = google_search(word, my_api_key, my_cse_id, num=5)
    # print(results)
    newDict = dict()

    for result in results:
        for (key, value) in result.items():
            if key in keyValList:
                if word in newDict['htmlSnippet']:
                    pass
                    newDict[key] = pprint.pprint(value)
        newDictList.append(newDict)
    print(newDictList)
```

Running the answer script

**The error code I got (Running the answer script):**

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/valizadavali/PycharmProjects/webScrape/GCS.py", line 39, in <module>
    items = google_search(word, API_KEY, CSE_ID, num=5)
  File "/Users/valizadavali/PycharmProjects/webScrape/GCS.py", line 11, in google_search
    return res['items']
KeyError: 'items'
```

Comment: `pprint` is used to send text on screen, not to create value which you can assing to variable. It always returns `None` so you need `newDict[key] = value` without `pprint.pprint()`. And if you want to format result then you have to do on your own using string function, string formating, for-loop, etc.

Comment: I don't understand your code - why you use `while`? why you convert item from `filteredList` if it is string, Why you covnert number `len(filteredList)` to string and why you compare string with number with word - ie `"Evrascon" < "6"`. You should use `print()` to display what you have in variables - ie. `print( str(items), str(len(filteredList) )` and you will see your mistakes. Using `print()` to check code is called "print debugging".

Comment: btw: you use the same name `items` as `items = 0` and later `for items in filteredList` - so finally in variable `items` you have word from `filteredList`, not value `0` and it makes no sense to add `1` to `items`,

Comment: I used while loop for searching each keyword while the length of filteredList greater than the keys in the dictionary, @furas if I do not use the str function I got an error like this `'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: you get error because you compare word `"Evrascon"` with number `6`. Use `print(items)` before `while` and you will see what you have in variable and you will understand your mistake. `for items in filteredList` gives you word from list, not index of this word. It is not `for items in range(len(filteredList)):`

Comment: with the `for items in range(len(filteredList)):` i get the answers but there are problems like the first index of the list is not searched and also at the end of the code I got an error like `list index out of range`

Comment: if you get error then show full error in question. We can't run code to see this error.

Comment: problem can be also that you add `1` to `items` so you create wrong index which doesn't exist in list - so don't add 1. If you have to count how many times you use loop then use different variable - don't use `items` for this.

Comment: I see error message and I' sure you get it because you add 1 to items. So first you get `filteredList[1]` and you skip `filteredList[0]` and you don't get result for first word. At the end you get `filteredList[6]` but last word is `filteredList[5]` and you get error message.

Comment: oh, i think i also understand the problem here but how can i debug it?

Comment: simply don't add 1 to `items`. `for`-loop should gives you correct indexes and you don't have to add 1 and you don't have to compare it with `len(filteredList)`. if you have to debug it then simply use `print()` to see values in variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have API keys to run this code but I see few mistakes:

When you use

```
for items in filteredList:
```

then you get word from list, not its index so you can't compare it with number.

To get number you would use

```
for items in range(len(filteredList)):
```

But instead of this version better use first version but then use `items` instead of `filterd[items]` in

```
results = google_search(items, my_api_key, my_cse_id, num=5)
```

If you choose version with `range(len(filteredList)):` then don't add 1 to items - because then you get numbers `1..6` instead of `0..5` so you skip first element `filteredList[0]` and it doesn't search first word. And later you try to get `filteredList[6]` which doesn't exist on list and you get your error message.

```
for word in filteredList:

    results = google_search(word, my_api_key, my_cse_id, num=5)
    print(results)    

    newDict = dict()

    for result in results:
        for (key, value) in result.items():
            if key in keyValList:
                newDict[key] = value
        newDictList.append(newDict)

    print(newDictList)
```

BTW: you have to create `newDict = dict()` in every loop.

---

BTW: standard `print()` and `pprint.pprint()` is used only to sends text on screen and always returns `None` so you can't assign displayed text to variable. If you have to format text then use string formatting for this.

---

**EDIT:** version with `range(len(...))` which is not preferred in Python.

```
for index in range(len(filteredList)):

    results = google_search(filteredList[index], my_api_key, my_cse_id, num=5)
    print(results)    

    newDict = dict()

    for result in results:
        for (key, value) in result.items():
            if key in keyValList:
                newDict[key] = value
        newDictList.append(newDict)

    print(newDictList)
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import requests

API_KEY = "AIzXXX"
CSE_ID = "013XXX"

def google_search(search_term, api_key, cse_id, **kwargs):
    service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)
    res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id, **kwargs).execute()
    return res['items']

words = [
    'Semkir sistem',
    'Evrascon',
    'Baku Electronics',
    'Optimal Elektroniks',
    'Avtostar',
    'Improtex',
#    'Wayback Machine'
]

filtered_results = list()

keys = ['cacheId', 'link', 'htmlTitle', 'htmlSnippet', ]

for word in words:
    items = google_search(word, API_KEY, CSE_ID, num=5)

    for item in items:
        #print(item.keys()) # to check if every item has the same keys. It seems some items don't have 'cacheId'

        row = dict() # row of data in final list with results 
        for key in keys:
             row[key] = item.get(key) # None if there is no `key` in `item`
             #row[key] = item[key] # ERROR if there is no `key` in `item`

        # generate link to cached page
        if row['cacheId']:
            row['link_cache'] = 'https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:{}:{}'.format(row['cacheId'], row['link'])
            # TODO: read HTML from `link_cache` and get full text.
            # Maybe module `newpaper` can be useful for some pages.
            # For other pages module `urllib.request` or `requests` can be needed.
            row['html'] = requests.get(row['link_cache']).text
        else:
            row['link_cache'] = None
            row['html'] = ''

        # check word in title and snippet. Word may use upper and lower case chars so I convert to lower case to skip this problem.
        # It doesn't work if text use native chars - ie. cyrylica
        lower_word = word.lower()
        if (lower_word in row['htmlTitle'].lower()) or (lower_word in row['htmlSnippet'].lower()) or (lower_word in row['html'].lower()):
            filtered_results.append(row)
        else:
            print('SKIP:', word)
            print('    :', row['link'])
            print('    :', row['htmlTitle'])
            print('    :', row['htmlSnippet'])
            print('-----')


for item in filtered_results:
    print('htmlTitle:', item['htmlTitle'])
    print('link:', item['link'])
    print('cacheId:', item['cacheId'])
    print('link_cache:', item['link_cache'])
    print('part of html:', item['html'][:300])
    print('---')
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the whole content of the news? Also, how to filter the output that does not include the selected words.

Comment: to get whole content probably you would have to visit page `newDict['link']` and get content from this page. But every page has different construction and it can be problem to get text without tags and other elements. Some pages may need also passwords to get access. I don't remeber if Google has archive with all pages. Eventually you can try to find pages on [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/)

Comment: To filter you can use `if word in text:` to keep items which have word in text - `if (word in newDict['htmlSnippet']) or (word in newDict['htmlTitle']): newDictList.append(newDict)`

Comment: can i use multiple words like a pre-selected list of words?

Comment: standard `if word in text:` can't use list of words but using `for word in list_of_words:` you can check all words. When yo find word then add item to list and use `break` to exit `for`-loop and skip checking other words because you could add the same item many times.

Comment: read about [Google Cache](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1687222?hl=en) which keep all visited pages so you don't have to visit original page. In items which you get with your code I see `cacheID` which maybe could be used to get full page - but it will be full HTML and you would have to search text in HTML.

Comment: I have updated the code, for filtering out the output for the pre-selected words, but it returns error

Comment: I got some pages from cache creating link `'https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:{}:{}'.format(item['cacheId'], item['link'])`

Comment: how can I use it in the script? q=?

Comment: you would have to use modules like `urllib.request` or `request` to read HTML from page  - ie. `response = requests.get( 'https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:{}:{}'.format(item['cacheId'], item['link']) )` And after reading HTML you can use `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` to search in HTML - but every page may have different structure so news can be in different place in HTML - in different tag or tags.

Comment: I added code which generate link to cache and use `requests` to get HTML from cache. Maybe using module `paperclip` you could get news from some HTML but probably you will have to search in every HTML individually - and it is never-ending job. I tested code with own API KEY.

Comment: correction: not module `paperclip` but [newspaper](https://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: thanks a lot. Is it possible to make the results filtered by date for newer comes first then the older ones?

Comment: Google doesn't give information about date so you can't filter or sort results by date. In documentation for [Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list) I found only option to restrict results by date - ie. last 5 days probably will be `list(q=..., restrictDate='d[5]')`. There is also option `sort` but there is no information how to write expression to sort by date - `list(q=..., restrictDate='d[5]', sort='???')`

Comment: I couldn't test code from last comment because I reached daily limit for free requests - 100.

Comment: I am planning to parse according to the cached websites (each website has its own soup). Secondly, `lower_word = word.lower() if (lower_word in row['htmlTitle'].lower()) or (lower_word in row['htmlSnippet'].lower()) or (lower_word in row['html'].lower()): filtered_results.append(row`' in this line i want to change the words to restrictedwords list and if the news include restricted words then filter it out

Comment: I was thinking to put this line in function  - ie. `check_restriction()` - which would use `for`-loop to test more words and this function should return `True` or `False` - `if not check_restriction(row): filtered_results.append(row)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201510/discussion-between-vali-valizada-and-furas).

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/valizadavali/PycharmProjects/webScrap/GCS.py", line 31, in <module>
    items = google_search(word, API_KEY, CSE_ID, num=5)
  File "/Users/valizadavali/PycharmProjects/webScrap/GCS.py", line 11, in google_search
    return res['items']
KeyError: 'items'` It returns an error, i am seraching 10 values.

Comment: `print(res)` to check what you get. Error shows that `items` doesn't exists but in `res` can be message about error. Free acccount has daily limit 100 requests. Maybe this is the problem - maybe in `res` will be information about this.

Comment: it returns nothing when I am running the `print(res)`, and also it does not occur because of the daily limit, because it does not reach to the limit.

Comment: it is strange that it returns nothing. I would expect it display `dict()` or `None`. As for limit - you have 6 words so you make 6 request in one run, and limit is 100 requests - so after running code 17 times (100/6 = 16.666) you can reach the limit. Yesterday when I was testing code I reached limit in few minuts.

Comment: I run the script three times and the code returns the error on the same line, like it returns values for 5 searches but then stops each time

Comment: I find the problem, there are values that when we are searching it returns only 2 result so not 5 as we declare in the line `items = google_search(word, API_KEY, CSE_ID, num=5)` . Is it possible to make the `num` key variable for the situations like that?